# Prove $\omega + \omega_1 = \omega_1$

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I am assuming that $\omega_1$ is the first uncountable ordinal and I'm using ordinal arithmetic.

I have so far that if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are ordinals, then $\alpha + \beta$ = sup{$\alpha + \gamma$ | $\gamma < \beta\}$ where $\beta$ is a limit ordinal.

So since $\omega$ and $\omega_1$ are both ordinals, can I say that $\omega + \omega_1$ = sup{$\omega + \gamma$ | $\gamma < \omega_1 \}$?

And then I'm not sure where to go with this.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Yes, by definition of ordinal arithmetic, since $\omega_1$ is a limit ordinal, this is true.

Comment: You already asked that.

Comment: WLOG, w_1 is von-Neumann. w_1 contains w*w= (w+w+w+w...). Noting this is a presegment w_1 = w+w+w+w+...+z . But this is just w+(w+w+w+...+z) so w_1=w+w_1.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of nice facts that should help you.

- First of all, the sum of two countable ordinals is countable (for the simple reason that the union of two countable sets is countable).  This should give a nice upper bound for $\omega + \omega_1$.
- Secondly, note that $\alpha + \beta \geq \max \{ \alpha , \beta \}$ for all $\alpha, \beta$, which gives a nice lower bound for $\omega + \omega_1$.

Comment: Will you explain the second point please?

Comment: @C.K: I'm a bit unclear about exactly what kind of explanation you want. Do you see how this fact gives a lower bound for $\omega + \omega_1$? or are you just uncertain about it's truth (or a proof of it)?

Comment: This is a correct argument, but it makes it seem like $\omega_1$ is somehow special, while for any ordinals $\alpha,\beta$, if $\beta\geq \omega\cdot\alpha$, then $\alpha+\beta=\beta$.

Comment: @ArthurFischer I wasn't sure how this fact gives a lower bound for $\omega$ + $\omega_1$

Comment: @C.K: Well, plug in $\alpha = \omega$ and $\beta = \omega_1$ into that inequality, and what do you get?

Comment: @ArthurFischer: $\omega$ + $\omega_1$ ≥ max{$\omega$ , $\omega_1$}.

Comment: @C.K: And what is $\max \{ \omega , \omega_1 \}$?

Comment: @tomasz: Yeah, I admit that this isn't the most generic way to arrive at this result. (But I would suggest that there _is_ something special about $\omega_1$.)

Comment: @ArthurFischer: not as far as ordinal arithmetic is concerned. And in general, that depends on the point of view. Your $\omega_1$ might be pretty countable for someone else. ;)

Comment: @ArthurFischer: is it $\omega_1$? Or have I lost track? Would you mind giving a technical definition of max{x, y} please?

Comment: @C.K: Of course it is $\omega_1$. ($\omega_1$ is the least uncountable ordinal, and every ordinal greater than $\omega_1$ is also uncountable, but $\omega$ is countable, so it must be that $\omega < \omega_1$.)

Comment: @ArthurFischer: okay that is becoming clearer. Also can you give a way to explicitly prove that  α+β≥max{α,β} ? Thanks

Comment: @C.K: As with most things regarding ordinals: by induction! (At a somewhat higher level, you can show that ordinal addition is non-decreasing with respect to both summands, and so $\alpha = \alpha + 0 \leq \alpha + \beta$ and $\beta = 0 + \beta \leq \alpha + \beta$.)